# How do I resize code editor window programmatically with a Visual Studio extension?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I really like how Visual Studio Code snaps and resizes split editor windows. Since I couldn't find anything similar in its bigger brother Visual Studio 2017, I'm trying to write a simple extension to achieve the same result.

Using the "Editor View Adornment" boilerplate I discovered that I can access the code editor window, in form of a IWpfTextView; however, this interface does not offer any setter for its positioning and size.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean snap and resize split editor windows in Visual Studio Code like this:
[image]

It is supported by VS2017, click "Window\New Vertical Tab Group" option:
[image]

You'll get the code editor splited like this:
[image]

Comment: Of course I can do this, but in VS Code you can drag the splitter to make one of the panels smaller and at a certain point it "snaps": from there on, every time you click in the smaller panel it grows, resizing the other panel automatically.