# Maximize current split tab group in Visual Studio 2017 or 2019

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio Code has a nice feature that allows automatic expansion of currently selected tab group (called editors) once you select a document.

How this feature works can be seen [in these release notes of VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_26#_grid-automated-maximize-of-minimized-editors).

Is there an extension to obtain the same effect in Visual Studio 2017 or 2019? [I've asked something similar a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43275090/how-do-i-resize-code-editor-window-programmatically-with-a-visual-studio-extensi) but never managed to develop the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for all visual studio extensions on visual studio market place.
 https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=toggle&target=VS&category=All%20categories&vsVersion=&sortBy=Relevance

I search there for an extension like you described but didn't found. So until today your answer is no.

Comment: Thank you and sorry if I don't award the bounty here but the answer is really too generic, the marketplace is the first place I looked into.

Comment: No problem. I just want to help